# Add dialog box when the program is clossed

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I want to add an option when somebody closes the frame to check if are there any thread running and if there are any I want to display a dialog box which should ask the user if he really wants to exit. The problem is that no matter which is the option of the user the program closes anyway.

Here is what I tried:

```
private void addActionWhenFrameIsClosed( )
{

    addWindowListener( new WindowAdapter( )
    {
        public void windowClosing( WindowEvent e )
        {
            if( isThereAnyThreadRunning( ) )
            {
                int dialogButton = JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION;
                int dialogResult = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog( null, "There are some threads running... "
                                                                        + "\nAre you sure you want to exit?",
                                                                  "Warning", dialogButton );

                if( dialogResult == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
                {
                    dispose( );
                }

            }
        }
    } );
}
```

Comment: At a guess, you have the `defaultCloseOperation` set to something other then `DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE`, which means that the API will perform some operation (either closing/hiding the window or terminating the JVM) automatically, regardless of what you might try and so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try adding this line of code as first line in `addActionWhenFrameIsClosed`

`setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);`